# findElementsByTagName of multiple tags in correct order on HTML page.

Tags: java, html, webdriver

I'm using WebDriver to retrieve and autofill forms in Firefox in the following way.

```
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
List<WebElement> inputElements = driver.findElementsByTagName("input");
List<WebElement> selectElements = driver.findElementsByTagName("select");
List<WebElement> allElements = new ArrayList<WebElement>(inputElements);
allElements.addAll(selectElements);
```

When I cycle through the allElements List, I first see all the 'input' elements, then all the 'select' elements. Is there a way to retrieve all these elements in the order they occur on the page? I wish findElementsByTagName() would take a REGEX like:

```
driver.findElementsByTagName("(input|select)");
```

Any clever ways to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into using xPaths. They should give you all the functionality you will need.

Comment: I've been trying to avoid xPaths because it looks like they're meant for well-formed pages, where the pages I'm attempting to navigate are... not necessarily well formed. Am I wrong? I'll quickly admit I've only been working with WebDriver for a couple weeks at most.

Comment: I find them to be helpful regardless. As long as you have a stable pattern it will work fine.